# Random Error on getGeoCode Rgooglemaps

Tags: r, google-maps, geocoding

I get a random number of errors that come back as NA when I try to geocode a lot of places using rgooglemaps getGeoCode function. Can anyone tell me why? (Reproducible code below)

```
library(RgoogleMaps)
library(foreach)
###Replicating a large search data###
PlaceVector <- c(rep("Anchorage,Alaska", 20), rep("Baltimore,Maryland", 20), 
rep("Birmingham,Alabama", 20))
iters <- length(PlaceVector)
###Looping to get each geocode###
geoadd <- foreach(a=1:iters, .combine=rbind) %do% {
  getGeoCode(paste(PlaceVector[a]))
}
geoadd <- as.data.frame(geoadd)
geoadd$Place <- PlaceVector
```

I get a random number of errors, usually around 15 where the latitude and longitudes in data frame geoadd come back as NA. I could loop it back on the NA's but that seems utterly inefficient. Do others have the same problem with the sample code provided?

Comment: Same here, both on Windows and Ubuntu. In the latter case, the following warning is thrown: `In min(iLng[iLng > iLoc]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350122/inconsistent-result-with-invalid-request-in-r-ggmap-geocode#new-answer), rate limiting can be circumvented by combining an outer loop structure (eg. `for` or `*apply`) with an inner `while` statement testing whether coordinates for a given location were successfully retrieved. In your case, this would look as follows:

```
geoadd <- foreach(a = 1:iters, .combine = rbind) %do% {
  gcd = getGeoCode(paste(PlaceVector[a]))

  while (all(is.na(gcd))) {
    gcd = getGeoCode(paste(PlaceVector[a]))
  }

  return(gcd)
}

all(!is.na(geoadd))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I switched to the googleway package and life got a lot better

Answer (score 0):

This is google's rate limiting.

If you run `getGeoCode` with `verbose=1` it will show you the URL it is accessing:

```
> getGeoCode("Brooklyn",verbose=1)
fetching  http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=Brooklyn 
      lat       lon 
 40.67818 -73.94416 
> getGeoCode("Brooklyn",verbose=1)
fetching  http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=Brooklyn 
lat lon 
 NA  NA 
Warning messages:
1: In min(iLat[iLat > iLoc]) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In min(iLng[iLng > iLoc]) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Now we can see that is generating the error message but isn't very helpful. Let's get the URL using `wget` on the command line a few times and see what happens:

```
wget 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=Brooklyn'
wget 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=Brooklyn'
wget 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=Brooklyn'
```

(you get the picture).

This for me returns responses that are either 1625 bytes long or 334 bytes long. Hello, that's a bit weird, what's in the 334 byte response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OVER_QUERY_LIMIT</status>
 <error_message>You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_</error_message>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

`getGeoCode` doesn't handle this gracefully, and insteads returns NAs and a non-informative warning.

Fix is to get a Google API key or use an alternative georeferencing system or figure out how long to wait between requests on the free API.